# Locating "Polynomial interpolation in several variables" by Alexander and Hirschowitz

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, paper-request

I'm looking for a digital copy of the already classical paper "Polynomial interpolation in several variables" by Alexander and Hirschowitz, which in particular solves the problem of the generic Waring rank. Can anyone provide a link?

Comment: I do not know whether a digital copy exists, but you might be interested by a  simpler proof due to Karen Chandler: [Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 353 (2001), 1907-1920](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2001-353-05/S0002-9947-00-02732-X/S0002-9947-00-02732-X.pdf).

Comment: @abx Thanks, this paper is nice. I'm still interested in locating the original one, but I will use your recommendation also.